# Photo comments for the question and answer

Tags: feature-request

If there were photo comment available then showing the questioner the result after correcting or changing the code would help very much.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zcBnQ.png)?

Comment: no not in link but in comment directly in same page.
just  the result.

Comment: @user000001 Wrong. That's a photo question. Here's what OP mean: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NEP8m.png

Comment: @RashimCatalanDhaubanjar I'd consider quitting the site, when I start seeing pictures in comments.

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ haha  same here but you know like you just wanna say like if you cahnge  yoour code as above then you would get this output :P

Comment: Use [SE Additional Optional Features](http://stackapps.com/q/6091) script. You can toggle inline image in comments on/off. See my answer.

Comment: "...showing the questioner the result after correcting or changing the code" This should be neither a comment, nor an image, but an edit.

Answer (score 7):

#### How can I display images in comments?

You can do this with the [SE Additional Optional Features](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) script.

One of the options for the script is:

> View links to imgur in comments inline (v1.2)

When this is enabled the comments in the question look like this:

[image]

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ so what are you considering..
 sorry just kidding

Comment: @RashimCatalanDhaubanjar lol ;)

Comment: @RashimCatalanDhaubanjar I'd simply consider not using that option :-)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ me too but i am talking about some special cases